# Replace excessive carriage returns with ReSharper

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

Is is possible to write a custom pattern in ReSharper to highlight any triple carriage returns? I am working with a team who all seem to have sticky Enter keys on their keyboards.

Comment: Why don't you use Code Cleanup to remove them?

Comment: That's an option, but I'd rather address the cause than the effect :-)

Comment: Then another option is to try StyleCop. They have many whitespace analyses.

Comment: No idea for highlighting that. But it's possible to just searching it by Wildcard search of Visual Studio (Ctr+Shift+F, Find what:=\n\n\n, Find options->Use:=Wildcards). Then you get a result list of all occurrences.

Comment: I've actually got that "\n[:b]*\n[:b]*\n" which takes care of whitespace as well. I am after something which will flag up in ReSharper realtime.